# An active connection to the MAC is required.Please ensure connection is established

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

Tried to connect to the MAC using visual studio 2019. I have managed to connect and get notification my connections has been established successfully. But am still getting warning to establish connection to the MAC.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately this has a simple workaround - you need to update Mono on your Mac. If you're on one of the more recent 15.7 builds of Visual Studio so I'd recommend https://dl.xamarin.com/MonoFrameworkMDK/Macx86/MonoFramework-MDK-5.10.1.57.macos10.xamarin.universal.pkg as it is latest stable release of Mono for Mac.

I believe this problem was fixed for 15.6 release, so before you update your mac it would be great if you could run `mono --version` and paste the output here so we can verify that it is just an old/out-of-date Mono issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 
I just downloaded Vs for Mac and use it to run the project

Comment: Good suggestion - glad I followed the link

Comment: Should mark this as an answer as its the top google result